# Set azure website instance count using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to scale out an Azure WebSite instance count(not instance size) using PowerShell?

I want to update an existing WebSite's instance count.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't scale Web Apps, but you scale the **App Service Plan** that they live in.

The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-azure-resource-manager-powershell/) has details on using PowerShell. Here, you'll want something like this:

```
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name ContosoAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName ContosoAzureResourceGroup -NumberofWorkers 9
```